Render elements from useState() Hook
I have a use-case where I want to store a list of components in the state of a useState() hook.
So far, this works for about 50%. I can properly store and render the components, but they are not updated properly. They do not seem to register state changes that are outside of the components themselves. Consider the following example:
function Test(): ReactElement {
    const [elements, setElements] = useState<Array<() => ReactNode>>([]);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div>
            <Input type="button" children="+" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)} />
            <Input type="button" children="Add" onClick={() => setElements([...elements, () => <div>{count}</div>])} />
            {elements.map((Element, index) => (
                <Element key={index}
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

This component does the following things:

It has a list of elements, created by the first useState() hook.
It has a counter, created by the second useState() hook. This counter can be increased using the first Input (the '+' one) component.
It has an Input labeled 'Add', which adds a new element to the list in the state.
It renders each of the elements in the state. Every one of these elements displays the counter.

As I said, this works fine, except that the elements from the state will display the counter value that they were created with and they will never update, even when they should after the counter was.
Is there a way to fix this, so that the elements will be updated in the expected manner?
Full/Further Context:
I am in the midst of writing a UI framework where each page has a Headerbar and content (plus a couple of other things that I have omitted for the sake of simplicity). I want to be able to add elements to the Headerbar from within the content (both of which are naturally different components), i.e. something like this:
<Page>
    <Headerbar>
        // Headerbar Elements, dynamically created 
    </Headerbar>
    <Content>
        // Other components that make up the content
    </Content>
</Page>

My current idea is to use a system like above where I store the elements in a state from where they can then be rendered in the Headerbar. However, if someone has a better way of achieving that, I am open to suggestions (hence this further context).

'...even when they should after the counter was' what makes you believe this? You are creating a closure over the current count value in your  onClick handler, so it is a static value, not a reference to the current state value.

I think it would be more helpful and you would get likely get more and better feedback if you elaborate a bit more on the context of what you're trying to do. It seems interesting, and the info you put is great to give an idea of what you're trying to do, but possible to explain in more detail what led you to try storing components in state.
It's definitely possible, but generally I've found it's likely possible in most cases to just store data and resolve have the components work in a way to render the data. If you have more information about your specific use case it would be cool, because often it's not that you'll be creating some sort of metaprogramming ui where the user can create components and they need to be stored as such, usually would be some config as data that then gets resolved. But if it a specific case you can add some mored details and can look at that.
As for the specific example, in react that won't work. I haven't used react in a while so I'm not too sure on the specifics, but I think the state is tied to the components, it's not like an independent signal object you can throw around and expect to work the same way regardless of context. I think cause it's still basically using classes, it makes it clearer to understand if you look at class components for this aspect of it. You can use the state in the component in which useState is declared in the render function, return in this case, and other hooks that expect to know how to use state. You can't just pass the state to another component through the closure of the main component (I think).
So for your case, if you really to make that work, you should change the way the count state variable is passed and make it a prop on the dynamic components.
So
const [elements, setElements] = useState<Array<() => ReactNode>>([]);

becomes
const [elements, setElements] = useState<Array<(props:{count:number}) => ReactNode>>([]);

and then when you create it it's like this
<Input
  type="button"
  children="Add"
  onClick={() =>
    setElements([
      ...elements,
      (props: { count: number }) => <div>{props.count}</div>,
    ])
  }
/>;

so it expects the count state, and when you render the components, you pass the state
{
  elements.map((Element, index) => <Element key={index} count={count} />);
}

Here's a replit that shows it with a few changes to make it work without dependencies https://replit.com/@maxmezzomo/test-state-components#src/App.tsx.
So going back to what I was mentioning at the start, this is great as a minimum reproducible example but clearly here you could just have another number state that counts the number of times to render the component that displays count, so just store data in state, and the render a predefined component that number of times. So if you have an example that better shows why it might be important to actually store a component in state please share and we can try and elaborate on the answer.
